# How would i connect from Eclipse to Tomcat to MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, android, eclipse, tomcat

I would like to know how to establish the link between eclipse - tomcat - MYSQL.
And also which version of mysql to download.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sysdeo plugin provides controls in eclipse for tomcat. For mysql check out tomcat connection pooling. I'll post more detail when ihave time.

### Edit

OK You can find the MySQL Java connector here

http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/

And information on configuration here
http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html

As far as I know, the current versions of MySQL and Tomcat are supported.

Comment: I've already did tomcat connection pooling in my servlet. I am currently connected to microsoft access. I would like to implement that in MYSQL.

Comment: There seems to be an error when i integrate it with eclipse. Do i have to use tomcat 6.0??

Comment: It says something about the jre not configured to run on tomcat 5.5 or earlier